# Налоговая информация для Admob

Tags: android, admob, реклама

Решил интегрировать рекламу в приложение, попробовал [tapcontext.com](https://www.tapcontext.com/). Там нужно заполнять налоговую форму, и  без нее никак, а заполнить ее без Американского "ИНН" нельзя (насколько я понял), а получить его нетривиальная для меня задача! Так вот, на Admob такая же ситуация или можно вывести деньги без труда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Admob переводит раз в месяц деньги в google adsense. А в нем уже можно указать свою налоговую информацию, а можно и не указать.